# A model for multiple nested proportions?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, binomial-distribution, proportion

I think this is more of a stats advice than code question so I've posted here rather than SO. My data looks like this (~300 more sample rows).

```
> head(nest)
  GroupA GroupB SubA SubB Treat
1     45    100    3    6   Pos
2     43     80    2    5   Neg
3     64     70    0    4   Neg
4     75     76    2    5   Pos
5     53     65    0    3   Pos
6     54     83    2    3   Pos
```

**GroupA** and **GroupB** are counts of different things within each sample.

**SubA** and **SubB** are a counts of a small subset of the same things (i.e. nested).

**Treat** show two different types of sample *Pos* and *Neg*.

My hypothesis is that the proportion of the subset (**SubA/SubB**) is a greater than the proportions of the whole (**GroupA/GroupB**) - particularly in *Pos* sample types. This is suggested by plotting.

However I find that if I naively just treat each row separately and apply a `binom.test` for each then it's way underpowered (too few **SubA**, **SubB**). Given this and quite a few 0 counts in **SubA** ...

Is there a more statistically powerful way I can address this idea?

Particularly how might I model this in R?

Any pointers are very welcome. Thanks.